# What are these unpopulated holes on the Arduino Leonardo?

Tags: arduino, avr, pinout

None of the pinouts online mention these holes next to the power barrel and LEDs. Are they connected to anything?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They are for heat dissipation from the voltage regulator.  They're probably connected to GND and they serve to transmit heat from large tab on the voltage regulator to the ground plane on the back of the board.

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140951/whats-the-purpose-of-the-ground-plane