# Best way to test medium speed circuits without parasitic inductances

Tags: inductance, high-speed, prototyping

I'm working on a constant power source for some heat output science experiments using Arduino, low Rds N-MOSFETs and dead-time capable half bridge MOSFET driver.

I plan to run this at around 30 kHz and I'm trying to find a good way to make experiments. I know a breadboard is an absolute NO at this frequency, and I suspect some 3d wire mess would work fine although harder to maintain.

Is there any solution in the middle that may allow me to switch some components around? Are perf boards ok for this application? What about a smaller breadboard? What about if I remove some of the breadboard metal channels and leave the bare minimum? Does thicker wires help?

Any advice is appreciated. Some components are still in shipping so I didn't experiment much.

Comment: Have you considered an initial simulation (if at all possible) and then getting a 2-layer PCB made for the final circuit to test ?

Comment: I've simulated parts. I cannot simulate the IC measuring voltage across a shunt in order to maintain constant V*A. Also The real life performance seems to be worse than the simulation, partly due to the IC not being able to drive the mosfets fast enough. It's why I ordered drivers. 
Now the problem is I don't have exact models in any of my simulation software, and definitely no gate drivers. I also can only change a few parameters of the mosfets, not the gate capacitance or time delays so I figure I should do a practical test before ordering a pcb.

Comment: Can you point towards why "double layer" is something advantageous? I've only ever designed a single pcb. Thanks.

Comment: A 2 layer PCB is just a PCB with copper on both sides. The two primary advantages are that it allows you to have tracks cross over each other by putting them on opposite sides, and that you can have a ground plane which minimizes ground impedance: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140951/whats-the-purpose-of-the-ground-plane.

Comment: If all the components are through-hole, hand wire a vectorboard. This seems to be a lost art. I have used both vectorboards with copper pads and those without. Copper pad boards are fairly cheap now, so that is what I mostly use. I use 24 AWG for most wires, 16 or 20 AWG when necessary.

Comment: Thanks @Mattman944. I had to look up "vectorboards". They seem to be the same as I call "perf-boards" but having wires instead of solder traces seems like a better way to experiment. I've specifically ordered through hole components. I've once soldered US-8 with 0.3mm leads and they're no fun. 2 out of 7 ruined :)
Thanks Winny also for the proofreading and everyone else for the interest and advice

Comment: I haven't had any problem with 30khz signals on a perforated board. I think Mattman944 comment is the way to go. It's cheap, quick, modifiable (to an extent) , some copper can be removed if need be. You can solder small copper wires of all sizes as big as 16AWG.